# Add commas to Bootstrap Input and Output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a calculator that works pretty well, but I cannot figure out how to add currency to the input as well as commas to the input and output. Everytime I add it, my calculation breaks and displays `$NaN`. Can someone give advice?

```
function calculate() {
  var savingsVal = (jQuery('#savingsVal').val());
  var totalSavings = 0;




  if (filterValues(savingsVal)) {
    totalSavings = savingsVal * 0.15 * 3;

  }
  jQuery('#totalSavings').val('$' + totalSavings);
}


function filterValues(eVal) {
  return true;

}

jQuery('.results-area').hide();

jQuery('#calculator').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  calculate();
  jQuery('.results-area').show("slow");
});
```

Comment: You have to parse strings to numbers to do math and reformat back to strings with separators for display

Comment: @YoungKyunJin that will only get any numbers prior to any other characters

Comment: you really need to provide more info, like what is in #savingsVal (i.e. how it's formatted) and how you want the output formatted. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: well right now savingsVal is just an input text field and the numbers are as follows "123456" I would like a comma to be automatically added when users are typing: "123,456" I have gotten that to work, but it breaks my calculation and output.

I would also like my output to include commas in the number.